How to set `isActive` for NextUI NavBaritem?
Question:
I am new to React and Next.js. I am using NextUI components to create a NavBar. I want to highlight or the active NavBarItem when it is clicked to show what page you are on. I am not sure how to do this correctly.
I have tried to use the useRouter logic, but that creates an error in my code and my website just shows a white page when I import { useRouter } from "next/router";. I have alsoo tried using const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState('home'); and onClick() logic, but that didn't seem to work either.
I was wondering if there are any suggestions to solve this?
Here is the NavBar Component I am using:
NavBar Component:
"use client";

import { AcmeIcon } from "@/components/icons/Brands";
import { cn } from "@/utils/nextui/cn";
import { Button } from "@nextui-org/button";
import { Link } from "@nextui-org/link";
import type { NavbarProps } from "@nextui-org/navbar";
import {
  Navbar,
  NavbarBrand,
  NavbarContent,
  NavbarItem,
  NavbarMenu,
  NavbarMenuItem,
  NavbarMenuToggle,
} from "@nextui-org/navbar";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React from "react";

const menuItems = [
  "Home",
  "Features",
  "About Us",
  "Investing Framework",

];

export default function Component(props: NavbarProps) {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = React.useState(false);
 useRouter
  return (
    <Navbar
      {...props}
      isBordered
      classNames={{
        base: cn("border-default-100", {
          "bg-default-200/50 dark:bg-default-100/50": isMenuOpen,
        }),
        wrapper: "w-full justify-center bg-transparent",
        item: [
          "flex",
          "relative",
          "h-full",
          "items-center",
          "data-[active=true]:after:content-['']",
          "data-[active=true]:after:absolute",
          "data-[active=true]:after:bottom-0",
          "data-[active=true]:after:left-0",
          "data-[active=true]:after:right-0",
          "data-[active=true]:after:h-[2px]",
          "data-[active=true]:after:rounded-[2px]",
          "data-[active=true]:after:bg-secondary",
        ],
      }}
      height="60px"
      isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}
      onMenuOpenChange={setIsMenuOpen}
    >
      <NavbarMenuToggle className="text-default-400 md:hidden" />

      <NavbarBrand>
        <div className="rounded-full bg-foreground text-background">
          <AcmeIcon size={34} />
        </div>
        <span className="ml-2 font-medium bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-400 via-pink-500 to-red-500">humblFINANCE</span>
      </NavbarBrand>
      <NavbarContent
        className="hidden h-11 gap-4 rounded-full border-small border-default-200/20 bg-background/60 px-4 shadow-medium backdrop-blur-md backdrop-saturate-150 md:flex dark:bg-default-100/50"
        justify="center"
      >
        <NavbarItem>
          <Link className="text-default-500" href="/" size="sm">
            Home
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem>
          <Link className="text-default-500" href="/features" size="sm">
            Features
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem>
          <Link className="text-default-500" href="/about-us" size="sm">
            About Us
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem>
          <Link className="text-default-500" href="/investing-framework" size="sm">
            Investing Framework
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
      </NavbarContent>
      <NavbarContent justify="end">
        <NavbarItem className="ml-2 !flex gap-2">
          <Button
            className="bg-default-100 text-default-700 sm:bg-transparent sm:text-default-500"
            radius="full"
            variant="light"
          >
            Login
          </Button>
          <Button
            className="hidden border-small border-secondary-500/20 bg-secondary-500/10 text-secondary-800 sm:flex"
            color="secondary"
            radius="full"
            style={{
              boxShadow: "inset 0 0 4px #bf97ff70",
            }}
            variant="flat"
          >
            Get Started
          </Button>
        </NavbarItem>
      </NavbarContent>
      <NavbarMenu
        className="top-[calc(var(--navbar-height)_-_1px)] max-h-[70vh] bg-default-200/50 pt-6 shadow-medium backdrop-blur-md backdrop-saturate-150 dark:bg-default-100/50"
        motionProps={{
          initial: {opacity: 0, y: -20},
          animate: {opacity: 1, y: 0},
          exit: {opacity: 0, y: -20},
          transition: {
            ease: "easeInOut",
            duration: 0.2,
          },
        }}
      >
        {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
          <NavbarMenuItem key={`${item}-${index}`}>
            <Link className="w-full text-default-500" href="#" size="md">
              {item}
            </Link>
          </NavbarMenuItem>
        ))}
      </NavbarMenu>
    </Navbar>
  );
}


I am trying to use usePathName as we speak...

useSelectedLayoutSegment is what you need to use here.
const currentPath = useSelectedLayoutSegment()
let isActive = currentPath === “your-path-without-any-slashes”

Docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-selected-layout-segment

If you are using Next 14+ App Router, you can also try to use the usePathname Client Component hook:
NextJS Doc
'use client'
 
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function Component() {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  return 
   ...
    <NavbarItem isActive={pathname === "/pathname"}>
   ...
}

